# how to animate itemSize from UICollectionViewFlowLayout?

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionview

I'm using a `UICollectionView` to display a set of graphics on several rows and columns. User can use `pinchGesture` to zoom in / zoom out.

When user zoom in the graph size increases and user zoom out the graph size decreases. To change the size of graph I'm just changing the property `itemSize` from `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. It works great but I'm unable to animate the change with the following code:

```
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.theCollectionView
                  duration:0.5f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                animations:^() {
                    _theFlowLayout.itemSize = cellSize;
                }
                completion:nil];
```

Any idea how to animate this change?

Regards,

Sébastien.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the collection view's `performBatchUpdates` method which will invalidate and re-query your layout, animating to any new values.

Something like this:

```
_theFlowLayout.itemSize = cellSize;
[self.theCollectionView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:nil];
```

You don't get to control the timing or curve of the animation, unfortunately.